# 5TB external HDD showing as 3.64 TiB

Tags: external-hard-drive

I bought a new 5TB Seagate backup plus portable external HDD. When connected with Manjaro, it shows only 3.64 TiB.

My calculation shows that 5TB should be more than 4.5 TiB. What could be wrong? On the HDD it is written as 5TB

Seems like something wrong. I tried the commands mentioned in the post and I get a WD hard drive instead of a Seagate one.  I think this one is not getting detected. I wasn't aware of a WD drive in my machine.

Comment: what does `gparted` show for the drive?

Comment: Which disk model ?

Comment: what's the output of `sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdX` and `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdX` and/or `lsblk -b /dev/sdX` for the drive? Replace X with the lowercase letter so that it matches your drive. Please append to the question if possible.

Answer (score 1):

3.64 TiB equal 4 TB. You maybe got a 4TB drive. The *Seagate® Backup Plus portable drive* [exists in 4 and 5 TB versions](https://www.seagate.com/www-content/datasheets/pdfs/bup-portable-ds1853-2-1512DS1853-3-1608-AMER-en_US.pdf#page=2). You can verify your drive with the number below the QR code on the disk label at https://verify.seagate.com/verify/